# Unhanded Exception (Could not find file)

Tags: c#, path

I created an installer for my project. I have successfully created it and installed but when I click "OK" for the next form which it will be filled up of details needed, an unhandled exception shows up.

[image: Unhandled Exception]

I do not know exactly where to locate this, I have changed all paths in my source code in all forms and still the same.

I used Visual Studio 2010  Express.

Comment: I would say the error is in line 42 of your source code

Comment: how can you say it is in line 42? @SirRufo

Comment: How can anyone say it is **not** in line 42?